# Excel / VBA - Changes to cell A1 reflected in B1 and vices versa (ie changes flow both ways)

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose you want cells A1 and B1 to always contain the same value. If the user can only modify A1, then all you need is "=A1" in B1.

What if you need the user to be able to modify both?

Is this only achievable with VBA code? If it's only achievable with VBA, and you need to link up several cells this way, what would be the most maintainable way to code it?

It seems that the Excel assumes you will only want to modify a value in one place. This is restrictive if you have large intimidating tables of data and you want to provide them with a simpler view in a separate tab.

Comment: http://help.lockergnome.com/office/excel-cells--ftopict997194.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is only possible through VBA and utilizing writing code to get triggered on the 'Change' event.  This link is a forum where someone gives an example code snippet.  Unfortunately it requires that you create an account, which I did not want to do:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/686940-cell1-cell2-and-cell2-cell1.html?p=2107235&viewfull=1#post2107235

Also here is a link to the documentation on Change events:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx